# Signing a message vs NFT to prove ownership

Tags: message-signing

What is the difference between signing a message using a Bitcoin address to prove ownership and NFT verification which will be used by [Twitter](https://twitter.com/TheSmarmyBum/status/1443259893411049475)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Signing a message is the easiest way to prove ownership for a private key associated with a Bitcoin address. Using NFTs doesn't prove ownership as explained by Charles Guillemet in this thread: https://twitter.com/P3b7_/status/1443470372758753283

> When you "Connect Wallet", you actually share your address (public key from a cryptographic perspective), it allows to browse the blockchain and to request JPEG to OpenSea, but it's not a proof of ownership.

2. Other issues: Privacy